# Sending HTTPS requests from SAP

Tags: https, sap

Does anyone have any information on the prerequisites for sending HTTPS requests from SAP? I'm able to send HTTP Posts ok but I can't get a request to be sent over HTTPS. This is from ABAP

I guess the core of the issue is what needs to be done to tell SAP to use a HTTPS connection not the standard HTTP.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: You need to expand on your question as it isn't clear what you are trying to do. Plus is this from an SAP ABAP stack or Java stack?

Comment: @Techboy - simple really,I want to send a POST over HTTPS not just HTTP. How do I configure SAP to handle the SSL handshake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you posting via an HTTP RFC?

If so:

- go to transaction SM59
- choose HTTP Connections to External Server
- Select the RFC
- Edit

**Technical settings tab:**

- Target Host = the server you are sending the HTTP POST to
- Service No = the port number (e.g. 443)

**Logon & Security tab:**

- Basic Authentication
- SSL = Active
- SSL Client Certificate = DEFAULT SSL Client (Standard) (this needs to be configured in transaction STRUST if not already done so)